# Basic Bootstrap on codepen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codepen

I'm trying to complete a project and I need the image and the text below it to be in the center. 
I've tryed everything, from center-block and just trying to change the col-md-x. 
However I can't find a good solution and I feel like as there is a col-md-8 and col-md-4 hidden somewhere.
As you can guess I'm trying to learn bootstrap and I'm a complete newbie.
Here's [the link](https://codepen.io/dpgian/pen/BRgBBq).

```
<div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg">

   <div class="caption text-center">
     <blockquote><em> Some more text </em></blockquote>
   </div>
 </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
     <h2> Title </h2>
     </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a css rule like `center-block`:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This is a CSS rule in bootstrap 3.3.7 : (REF [center-block.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/mixins/center-block.less))

But seems like they remove it for v4, now they are using `mx-auto` in v4: (REF [LINK HERE](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/3719ed4cb69fd8c75869158b086b4fc077e63e14/docs/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L7490-L7493))

```
.mx-auto {
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/hdl881127/pen/YVozxo

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">

        <h1 class="text-center text-primary"> Title </h1>
        <h2 class="text-center"> Some text </h2>

        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg">

          <div class="caption text-center">
            <blockquote><em> Some more text </em></blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
            <h2> Title </h2>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer in below link
[Updated code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmZJVL)

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Bootstrap has a class for center align i.e. text-center